# RailsAdmin - pass parameters to scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I defined several scopes on my model and use them in rails_admin.

```
scope :foo , ->() { where(status: 'active')}
...
list do
  scopes    [nil, 'foo']
```

I want to create scopes where I can pass parameters and then load those from rails_admin.  Something like this:

```
scope :bar , ->(query) { where(status: query)}
```

But because RA does not pass parameter I keep getting

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I am using Rails 4.1.14 with rails_admin 0.8.1 and mongoid 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this via creating custom action and then specify it to use index template.  It shows up next to List, Add New and other actions instead of below filters.

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  ...
  belongs_to :user,     counter_cache: true
  scope :by_user, ->(user) { where(user: user) } 
  ...
end
# in rails_admin.rb
class Myarticles < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
  RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
  register_instance_option :collection do
    true
  end
  register_instance_option :only do
    Article
  end        
  register_instance_option :controller do
    proc do
      @objects = Article.by_user(current_user)
      render :index
    end
  end
end
```

Related question [Rails_admin custom action specify template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980712/rails-admin-custom-action-specify-template-name)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using cancan. You can do this in the ability file:

```
  def initialize(user)
      can [:read], Profile, user_id: user.id
  end
```